# Bootstrap Button href Link with my Code?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have create an Button, it is also possible to add an "href" Link to this Code?
My Link dont work!

```
<button class="buttoncostum">

<a href="http://example.com/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"></span><font color="white"> <b>Example</b></a></font></button>
```

Sorry i am new with coding if the code looks bad;)
Thanks all!

Comment: I don't think a link inside a button is valid html

Comment: Can you tell me please an solution? Or if i can submit to an Page?

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Why you are using anchor inside button?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use bootstrap classes for the tag `a` without the `button` tag !

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Example
</a>
```

I cleaned up your HTML a bit, use CSS classes and IDs instead of inline CSS !

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap you can do that :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>
```

Comment: But this changes the color of text~_~